# Restrict COD payment if cart has Gift Certificate

Tags: php, opencart

How can we check by code in Opencart 2.0.3 that Cart contains Gift Certificate?

I want to disable cash on delivery (cod) payment mode if cart has Gift Certificate (opencart 2.0.3). Any code or idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that , In products you can set a status that you product is Gift Certificate or not , after that some case will arrive while order:

Customer can order products with Gift Certificate so you have to check if any product is  with Gift Certificate status  that shipped will not be COD

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cod.php model (catalog/model/payment/cod.php) and add condition if gift certificates exist.

Do you mean "voucher" with "gift certificate"

This is the actual model

```
 <?php
class ModelPaymentCOD extends Model {

    public function getMethod($address, $total) {
        $this->load->language('payment/cod');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id') . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')");

        if ($this->config->get('cod_total') > 0 && $this->config->get('cod_total') > $total) {
            $status = false;
        } elseif (!$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }

        $method_data = array();

        if ($status) {
            $method_data = array(
                'code'       => 'cod',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
                'terms'      => '',
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('cod_sort_order')
            );
        }

        return $method_data;
    }
}
```

You can add this condition:

```
if(isset($this->session->data['vouchers'])){ 
    $status = false;
}
```

It works for me.

If you don't have experience with php replace the code from file with this :

```
<?php
class ModelPaymentCOD extends Model {

    public function getMethod($address, $total) {
        $this->load->language('payment/cod');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id') . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')");

        if ($this->config->get('cod_total') > 0 && $this->config->get('cod_total') > $total) {
            $status = false;
        } elseif (!$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }

        if(isset($this->session->data['vouchers'])){ 
            $status = false;
        }

        $method_data = array();

        if ($status) {
            $method_data = array(
                'code'       => 'cod',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
                'terms'      => '',
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('cod_sort_order')
            );
        }

        return $method_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am referring purchasing of 'Gift Certificates '  (not voucher/coupon code)  at the time of checkout. Please confirm the above code works to restrict COD payment mode while purchasing 'Gift Certificates'                                             Refer Link: https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/voucher

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Make a backup of these files and try to do.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it.